# Updating tables with new data from API

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, synchronization

I'm looking to develop something for my client which will do the following:

1) Connect to MYOB and connect all customer & staff accounts.

2) Everyday at a certain time; connect to the **remote** MYOB system and check if there is any new data and update the current tables with the new data.

I'm stuck on number 2. How can I ensure the data is correct and up to date? I previously dropped all the tables and re-added them, but it simply takes too much time with over 2000 records.

Is there an alternative that will take less time and will improve efficiency? If so; what is the logical approach to take?

The database is MySQL and i'm using PHP/Laravel.

Comment: Is there any way by the time you compare and update, the user can delete any data. If not then you can go ahead with CRON job

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Channaveer Hakari for his solution:

I decided to create a database field called 'last_sync' which records the last synchronisation time. This is updated everytime a sync completes successfully.

The remote API had a timestamp for each customer request which was called 'LastModified' - I checked if LastModified > last_sync and then updated the database with the new information if so.

Comment: Oliver depending on which MYOB product you're connecting to you may also benefit from storing the RowVersion (for AccountRight Live v2) field of each record you're storing/syncing. We've written a best practice guide for these scenarios that you might glean some wisdom from too. http://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/best-practice-guides/storing-and-caching-data/

Comment: @developerjack I think I solved this with your help a few months ago. But row version sounds like a better idea than timestamps in terms of development. Thanks Jack!!